# Avoid mutating a prop directly when use vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I create an alert component in vue, like this

```
<template>
   <div class="alert-bg" v-if="view">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="message"> {{message}} </div>
        <div class="alert-control text-right mt-4">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" @click="onCancel" v-html="cancel"/>
            <button :class="btnStyle" class="btn ml-2" v-html="ok" @click="onSubmit"/>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    import $ from 'jquery';
    import 'imports-loader?window.jQuery=jquery,this=>window!widgster';

    export default { 
        name: 'Alert',
        props: {
            message: { default: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur' },
            cancel: { default: 'Cancel' },
            ok: { default: 'Yes' },
            btnStyle: { default: 'btn btn-primary' },
            view: { default: false }
        },

        methods: {
            onCancel(){
                this.view = false;
            },

            onSubmit(){
                this.$emit('onSubmit');
            }
        },

    };
</script>
```

then in main page I use it like this,

```
// html
<button class="btn btn-secondary" @click="confirm" v-html="'Confirm'"/>
<Confirm :view="alert.view"/>

// script
import Confirm from '@/components/modals/alert/alert';

export default {
  name: "Product",
  components: { Confirm },
  data() {
    return {
      alert: { view: false },
    }
  },

  methods: {
     confirm(){
        this.alert.view = true; // show alert
     }
  }
}
```

When I click confirm button, it's success to show alert, when I click cancel button the alert is close but I got error like this

```
[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "view"
```

then when I click confirm button again, the alert does not appear, how I can solve this problem? thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the prop directly from the child component(as vue said).
So the true way is:

```js
methods: {
  onCancel(){
    // this.view = false; <--- is wrong way
    this.$emit('update:view', false)
  }
  // ...
},
```

Then in parent pass it like this:

`<Confirm :view.sync="alert.view"/>`

Answer (score 0):

As vue.js guide says:

> All props form a one-way-down binding between the child property and
>   the parent one: when the parent property updates, it will flow down to
>   the child, but not the other way around. This prevents child
>   components from accidentally mutating the parent’s state, which can
>   make your app’s data flow harder to understand.

So you have to create component own state and and then modify state inside your component. Like this:

```
<script>
    import $ from 'jquery';
    import 'imports-loader?window.jQuery=jquery,this=>window!widgster';

    export default { 
        name: 'Alert',
        data() {
            return{
                componentView: this.view
            }
        },
        props: {
            message: { default: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur' },
            cancel: { default: 'Cancel' },
            ok: { default: 'Yes' },
            btnStyle: { default: 'btn btn-primary' },
            view: { default: false }
        },

        methods: {
            onCancel(){
                this.componentView = false;
            },

            onSubmit(){
                this.$emit('onSubmit');
            }
        }

    };
</script>
```

Comment: In this case you need to watch to `view` and update `componentView`